# PostgreSQL 3 Table Join Multiplying

Tags: sql, postgresql, cartesian-product

I have 3 tables. The first has the records I want. The other two have categories to be applied to the first table. If the lookup value from table3 is found in the description, I want to return that category. Else, return the category in table2. I think I have that logic correct, but the results are being multiplied. How can I limit the results to just the table1 records I want, but apply the correct category?

Here is my query with an example schema. It should only return the first 6 rows in table1 with whichever category is correct, but it returns 10. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fc6fa/49/0

```
SELECT table1.product_code, table1.date_signed, table1.description, 
CASE 
  WHEN lower(table1.description) LIKE ('%' || lower(table3.lookup_value) || '%') 
  THEN table3.category 
  ELSE table2.category 
END 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.psc_code = table1.product_code 
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.psc_code = table1.product_code 
WHERE date_signed = '2017-02-01';



create table table1 ( 
product_code int, 
date_signed timestamp, 
description varchar(20) 
); 

insert into table1 
(product_code, date_signed, description) 
values 
(1, '2017-02-01', 'i have a RED car'), 
(2, '2017-02-01', 'i have a blue boat'), 
(3, '2017-02-01', 'i have a dark cat'), 
(1, '2017-02-01', 'i have a green truck'), 
(2, '2017-02-01', 'i have a blue rug'), 
(3, '2017-02-01', 'i have a dark dog'), 
(1, '2017-02-02', 'i REd NO SHOW'), 
(2, '2017-02-02', 'i blue NO SHOW'), 
(3, '2017-02-02', 'i dark NO SHOW'); 

create table table2 ( 
psc_code int, 
category varchar(20) 
); 

insert into table2 
(psc_code, category) 
values 
(1, 'vehicle'), 
(2, 'vehicle'); 

create table table3 ( 
psc_code int, 
lookup_value varchar(20), 
category varchar(20) 
); 

insert into table3 
(psc_code, lookup_value, category) 
values 
(1, 'fox', 'animal'), 
(1, 'red', 'color'), 
(1, 'box', 'shipping'), 
(2, 'cat', 'animal');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to join 1 to many, and you only want one value.

```
SELECT table1.product_code, table1.date_signed, table1.description,
CASE 
  WHEN EXISTS (select 1 from table3
               where table3.psc_code = table1.product_code and
                     lower(table1.description) LIKE ('%' || lower(table3.lookup_value) || '%')) 
  THEN (select table3.category from table3 
        where table3.psc_code = table1.product_code and
              lower(table1.description) LIKE ('%' || lower(table3.lookup_value) || '%') limit 1)
  ELSE (select table2.category
        from table2
        where table2.psc_code = table1.product_code
        limit 1)
END 
FROM table1 
WHERE date_signed = '2017-02-01';
```

http://rextester.com/TQIY93378

```
+--------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------+
| product_code |     date_signed     |      description     | category |
+--------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------+
| 1            | 01.02.2017 00:00:00 | i have a RED car     | color    |
| 2            | 01.02.2017 00:00:00 | i have a blue boat   | vehicle  |
| 3            | 01.02.2017 00:00:00 | i have a dark cat    | NULL     |
| 1            | 01.02.2017 00:00:00 | i have a green truck | vehicle  |
| 2            | 01.02.2017 00:00:00 | i have a blue rug    | vehicle  |
| 3            | 01.02.2017 00:00:00 | i have a dark dog    | NULL     |
+--------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------+
```

Comment: I see that gets the right AMOUNT of results, but by my count, product_code 3 should never have a category, right? Why does it get animal in the first 3?

Comment: Thanks, that does it!

Answer (score 0):

Yep you will get a cartesian product on this one.

Your problem is that you have multiple rows of each product_code that match fro table1.  So when you join on table3, you get six records out with an id of 1.  The other join conditions don't pose a situation where you have multiple matches on both sides, so that is how you get six product code 1 rows, 2 product code 2 rows and 2 product code 3 rows.

The solution is to join in ways in which the foreign key is targetting a unique row in the target table.

This really ought to be a useful example of why normalization and key awareness matter.  Where you break the basic rules of functional dependencies, bad problems ted to multiply.